# Create MLP architecture for general learning

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I created a mlp that reads a very precise dataset (in the specific jurisdiction) and then perform the train and set of the same data. Then I perform the evaluation and finally save the model in pkl. Everything works ok, just that I would like to create a dynamic model, even using existing and external functions, to make the aforementioned model work with a generic dataset given in input chosen at random, making it as generic as possible.
thank you

```
import pandas
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC

from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.externals import joblib 


# load dataset
url = "iris.data"
names = ['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width', 'class']
dataset = pandas.read_csv(url, names=names)


# split  dataset 
array = dataset.values
X = array[:,0:4] 
Y = array[:,4]   
validation_size = 0.20
seed = 7
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed)


# Opzion  test
seed = 7
scoring = 'accuracy'

# Algo
models = []
models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression()))
models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('SVM', SVC()))


# Value
results = []
names = []
for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)


# 
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Confronto Algoritmi')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.boxplot(results)
ax.set_xticklabels(names)
plt.show()


# Preview
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(X_train, Y_train)
predictions = knn.predict(X_validation)
#
print(accuracy_score(Y_validation, predictions))
#Report
print(classification_report(Y_validation, predictions))


# Save
joblib.dump(knn, 'HomeWork2.pkl')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to go with Keras (with a GPU it will be faster):

Source: https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#training

```
# For a single-input model with 2 classes (binary classification):

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', input_dim=100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Generate dummy data
import numpy as np
data = np.random.random((1000, 100))
labels = np.random.randint(2, size=(1000, 1))

# Train the model, iterating on the data in batches of 32 samples
model.fit(data, labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
# For a single-input model with 10 classes (categorical classification):

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', input_dim=100))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Generate dummy data
import numpy as np
data = np.random.random((1000, 100))
labels = np.random.randint(10, size=(1000, 1))

# Convert labels to categorical one-hot encoding
one_hot_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes=10)

# Train the model, iterating on the data in batches of 32 samples
model.fit(data, one_hot_labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

Comment: Tank you for your answer, but this code accept all input? (Numeric and Text?) and this is a section of the exercise? missed the import function in head? tank you very much

Comment: What you ask doesn't exist... And that would be ... kinda stupid...
You don't process the way numeric values, text or categorical data.

My advice, forget about your idea to develop "one solution to rule them all", especially with a very basic knowledge in neural networks.

If you question is "solved", please mark it as solved

Comment: We are not here to do your homework. The MLP model is only a part of the solution you need to convert various data to a common ground.

Forget about the idea to have a model that does everything you might think of.

Comment: this is non a homweork, your solution is ok for my problem? tanks

Comment: Your problem isn't a problem and shouldn't be addressed. It is non sense to design a single model for any kind of problem. I gave you a MLP for numerical data, for the rest you have to look by yourself